# Refreshing page after ajax request and PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Good day!

Trying to refresh the page after submission of values with ajax and php function (to db). Tried doing it via ajax request success method, but it didnt seem to work.

javascript

```
function saveQuestionnaire() {
    /* some code */

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "createquestionnaire.php",
        data: {toDbQuestionnaire: toDbJson},
        success: function(data){
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

createquestionnaire.php

```
require("functions.php");

$obj = $_POST['toDbQuestionnaire'];
$obj = json_decode($obj);

if (isset($obj) && isset($obj->name) && $_SESSION['email']) {
    $Question->createQuestionnaireWithNameAndEmail($obj->name, $_SESSION['email'], $obj->quiz);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode("{result: true}");
}
```

The following function after that goes through properly and pushes values to DB. Although, to view the changes on the page, i need the page to refresh. How do i achieve that? As you can see, `window.location.reload()` didn't quite work.

**---- EDIT ----**

Apparently, this works like a charm. Why am i getting an error though?

```
error: function(data){
                window.location.reload();
            }
```

Comment: why do you use AJAX when you need to refresh the page.

Comment: Did you try to add a `console.log('pass')` right before your redirection? To see if your success function triggers.

Comment: print your error in console

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(data){
   if(data.success == true){ // if true (1)
      setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
           location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
      }, 1000); 
   }
}
```

use this in the success part

Answer (score 1):

can you change your createquestionnaire.php file like this,

```
    require("functions.php");

    $obj = $_POST['toDbQuestionnaire'];
    $obj = json_decode($obj);

    if (isset($obj) && isset($obj->name) && $_SESSION['email']) {
        $Question->createQuestionnaireWithNameAndEmail($obj->name, $_SESSION['email'], $obj->quiz);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $result = array('result'=>true);
        echo json_encode($result );
    }else{
        $result = array('result'=>false);
        echo json_encode($result );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

really sorry everyone. the reason for error was this part in createquestionnaire.php:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use location.reload instead of window.location.reload in success